# aspnet.core Seeding data using UserManager<IdentityUser>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I am trying to spin up an Identity Server instance, based on http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/8_aspnet_identity.html and using the code from https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/8_AspNetIdentity as my template but I am having trouble getting the seed data happening.

I have my program.cs and startup.cs as per the sample application. When I call

```
var userMgr = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```

from the `SeedData.EnsureSeedData` method, which comes after

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            using var scope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();

            var userMgr = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```

I get the following error.

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.
```

How do I register services for `ILogger<UserManager<IdentityUser>>>` ?

I feel like I am missing something obvious but can't see what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I seed data using user manager

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var host = BuildWebHost(args);
                using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    SeedData.Initialize(services).Wait();
                }

                host.Run();
            }
}
```

And in seed data class

```
private static async Task SeedUser(User user, ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
            string[] roles)
        {
            var password = new PasswordHasher<User>();
            var hashed = password.HashPassword(user, "123456");
            user.PasswordHash = hashed;
            var userStore = new UserStore<User>(context);

            await userStore.CreateAsync(user);
            await EnsureRole(serviceProvider, user.Email, roles);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

You can view my full code [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Entities/Data/SeedData.cs)

Let me know if you need any help.